# Can CYK algorithm be used even if the grammar is ambiguous?

Tags: context-free, parsers

Can CYK algorithm be used for ambiguous context free grammar?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [CYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm), and related algorithms such as [Earley's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) and [GLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser), work for ambiguous grammars. CYK requires converting the grammar into Chomsky Normal Form first; doing so does not affect its ambiguity.